Failure on deploying node.js applications in cpanel
Unfortunately I'm having difficulties hosting my node.js application. I'm having errors and failures. Firstly, cpanel said that there was a possible error in package.json, it said that it contained errors in the command/test file, so I deleted it because I wasn't really using it, but now I was left with the following issues shown in the images (See the image in Stackoverflow's generated link).
Note
The front was made in angular, the back in express.js and hosting in cpanel
I tried to delete dependencies that didn't seem to be being used, such as g and global in my package.json and package-lock.json.
Delete devDependencies (nodemon) from package.json and package-lock.json

These messages are not errors, but just warnings.
You won't need to run scripts at all.
Just run "Executar a instalação do NPM" to install dependencies and restart the app. This may resolve the issue.
Check the  Passenger configuration on the .htacces file and cPanel Errors to get more information.
